# How to show "Your Location " option in Google maps Place Autocomplete TextView

Tags: android, google-maps

How can I give the user the option of using their current location in `place auto complete fragment`

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
    />
```

Like this 
[image: The top field is a Text View with a placeholder that says "Choose starting point" and below it is the option "Your location".]

Comment: no Just fragment and `setOnPlaceSelectedListener()`
its working fine for place search

Comment: How did you achieve that

Comment: @BryanKimani that is the question